# How to retrieve result from a function returning an ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have a function that is expecting a result from an ajax call and assign it to the variable to result is successfully assigned to the variable but my problem is that how can I extract it?

Here is my code, I tried using `$.each` to variable but it is undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var branches = GetBranches();

        console.log(branches);

        //$.each(branches.d, function (key, val) {
        //    console.log(val.BranchCode);
        //})

        function GetBranches() {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testWS.asmx/GetBranches',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is my screenshot for the `console.log(branches)`

[image]

I want to retrieve/extract data from the responseJSON. How can possibly do this?

Comment: Have you ever heard about success call back.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The jqXHR Object

`$.ajax()` returns jQuery `XMLHttpRequest(jqXHR)` object.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).
>   These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when
>   the $.ajax() request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple
>   callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the
>   request may have completed. (If the request is already complete, the
>   callback is fired immediately.) Available Promise methods of the jqXHR
>   object include:
>
> 1. jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
> 2. jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
> 3. jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });
> 4. jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});

So,

```
$(function () {
    var branches = GetBranches(); // return you jqXHR Object.
    brances.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { // assign callback function when your AJAX request completes.
        console.log(data); // here is data you are looking for
    });

    function GetBranches() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'testWS.asmx/GetBranches',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        });
    }
});
```

### Refer [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [Deferred Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
   function GetBranches() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'testWS.asmx/GetBranches',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'JSON',
           success: function(response) {
                  return response;
               }
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX success

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var branches = GetBranches();

        console.log(branches);



        function GetBranches() {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testWS.asmx/GetBranches',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON',
success:function(data){
// Here you will get the data returned from response
}
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```